# application didReceiveRemoteNotification not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm implementing push notifications with Parse's push framework. I have everything in my application delegate set up as Parse indicates. I know that it is working because when I run the sample code Parse provides, the push notification works correctly (and when I place a breakpoint in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, I can see that it is called).

```
PFQuery* pushQuery = [PFUser query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"deviceType" equalTo:@"ios"];  

// Send push notification to query
[PFPush sendPushMessageToQueryInBackground:pushQuery
                               withMessage:@"Hello World!"];
```

When I run the above code in my app (on a test button press), I immediately receive a notification that says "Hello World". So the backend is working properly, and I'm capable of receiving notifications.

This is the code I ultimately want to run:

```
PFQuery* usersQuery = [PFUser query];
PFQuery* pushQuery = [usersQuery whereKey:@"joinedIDsAr" containsAllObjectsInArray:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myID, nil]];   //get all users who subscribed to my broadcast 

//NSArray* usersAr = [pushQuery findObjects];

[PFPush sendPushMessageToQueryInBackground:pushQuery
                               withMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ has a new message for you to share!", myDisplayName]
                                block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * __nullable error)
                                {
                                    if(succeeded)
                                    {
                                        NSLog(@"Success!");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        NSLog(@"ShareScheduleVC::sendSharePushNotif: error: %@", error);
                                    }
                                }];
```

When the above code executes, I get the success message (and error is always nil). However the breakpoint in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is *not* hit, and I don't receive a push notification. The commented-out line with the `usersAr` was my attempt to test if the query was retrieving the correct objects; it was, my PFUser object was returned. So the problem isn't an empty query.

I understand that a lot of changes were made between the initial test code and my code above, so I took Parse's example code and simply changed one line and the message text:

```
PFQuery* usersQuery = [PFUser query];
PFQuery* pushQuery = [usersQuery whereKey:@"joinedIDsAr" containsAllObjectsInArray:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myID, nil]];   //get all users who subscribed to my broadcast 

// Send push notification to query
[PFPush sendPushMessageToQueryInBackground:pushQuery
                               withMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ has a new message for you to share!", myDisplayName]];
```

And I get the same problem; `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not being called, I can confirm that my query contains my PFUser object, and I receive no notification.

I'm pulling my hair out... Has anyone else had this problem? Or can spot an obvious mistake I've made? Any clue on where to start would be appreciated.  All of this is happening immediately after I create the push notification, while my app is running... There is no issue of running in the background, I haven't gotten that far yet! I just want to be able to send a custom notification.

(Also, I can change the message text freely without causing a problem... It's when I modify the query to look for something other than `deviceType` that I get a problem. But I can see that the query isn't empty! The only guess I have at this point is that somehow my PFUser object isn't connected to my device, so even though it's looking for my user account it can't find my device. But why would the test code work, then?

Comment: Are you sure that first query works as you've pasted it in? I'm surprised it works, because you should need to provide PFInstallation objects to the push query, not PFUser objects.

Comment: @rickerbh I am sure, yes. I've tried it both ways, with the PFInstallation and the PFUser, and they both work identically. Parse's documentation says to use [PFUser query] when you want PFUser objects, so I changed it and it still worked exactly the same, which has been another source of confusion for me... I was reading the docs on the PFInstallation, and from what I understood it shows values for the current install on the device? So I don't even see how it queries all the users that exist on the server... This whole thing is perplexing me.

Comment: I think would be better to send the push notification from the Cloud Code of Parse, implementing a custom cloud code function, that for sure it works, and secondly is more secure ( disabling the possibility to send push notification from clients in your parse settings account ). So, just sending the list of objectId for the user who are subscribed, then the cloud function will do the works for you. It could be useful if you plan to do it also in different platform such as Android, since is server side

Comment: Is the push even showing in your push databrowser? Could you please make a screenshot of it, so that we can see the exact targeting?